# Google Maps API, прозрачный слой поверх карты

Tags: javascript, css, html5, вёрстка, google-maps-api

По задумке дизайнера поверх карты Google должен быть цветной прозрачный слой, но сам маркер с текстом должен быть над этим слоем. Скажите, это вообще возможно сделать через Google Maps API? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays?hl=ru
вот так ?

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn, возможно,  нужно попробавать, через наложения и привязку к координатам все это сделать